# Magento how to download plugin directly by link via curl or wget

Tags: curl

I would like to download single plugin zip file with curl or wget and I always get **FORBIDDEN** response.

As an example let use this magento-language-es_es-100.4.0.0.zip it's available under

https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/language-es_es/magento-language-es_es-100.4.0.0.zip

When I try to just use curl with -u Public Key:Private Key (which I obtain from my profile https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/) I always get FORBIDDEN.

What is wrong with this, maybe I need to add some additional Headers or change method?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody know the answer? Seems that it's not a complex problem, but I'am new in Magento world and can't handle this